# Only show description in dayGridMonth

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to work with extendedProps, but when i try to show info.event.extendedProps.description in timeGridWeek or timeGridDay it doesn't (it say "undefined"), only in dayGridMonth. I have read the docs, but i don't know how to show these non-standard properties.

The events are displayed correctly.

(Sorry for my poor english)

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction', 'bootstrap', 'timeGrid', 'rrule' ],
          height: 'parent',
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
          },
          titleFormat: {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            day: '2-digit'
          },
          defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
          selectable: true,
          editable: true,
          navLinks: true,
          weekNumbers: true,
          nowIndicator: true,
          locale: 'es',
          minTime: '08:00:00',
          maxTime: '22:00:00',
          weekends: false,
          eventOrder : 'color',
          eventSources: [
            'carga_citas.php',
            'carga_sesiones.php'
          ],
          eventClick: function(info) {
            alert(info.event.extendedProps.description);
          }
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Without seeing your event data (in JSON format, please), it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Hello ADyson, and thanks for your reply.
I just realized that the problem was precisely in the event data, the "description" field was wrong in one of the eventSources.

Comment: Hi, So, basically the issue is sorted out now ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved.